# Playlist loop in AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, media-player, flash

I'm very bad with Flash and I just can't do this.
I have php generated playlist.
I get it with LoaderInfo(), then with split() the data is added to array.

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var str:String = paramObj.playlist;
var array:Array = str.split(",");
```

Here is the problem. I know how to play 1 song from the playlist, once or in the loop with code like this:

```
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete, false, 0,
true);
function onLoadComplete(evt:Event):void {
channel = sound.play();
var pauseSong:Number = channel.position; 
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);
}
function soundCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {

channel = sound.play();
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);
}
```

, but I cant make code to play in loop all songs in playlist -first, second, etc, first...
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an array of your loading sounds, put a separate listener onto the first (0th) sound of your list that will initiate playback, all others should have another listener that will just notify your program that the sound is loaded. Once the first sound started playing, you add a listener to `channel` that will select next song and play it if it's available. If it's not available, your code should wait in a frame-based loop (Event.ENTER_FRAME listener with one single check) until it will finally load, and resume playlist playback.